# Sequelize Migration addIndex not adding index in descending order

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration

I am trying to create an index on an existing table (Postgres) on a date column so that I can get the latest posts first

Model file feeditem.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const FeedItem = sequelize.define('FeedItem', {
    feedItemId: {
      //...
    },
    pubdate: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      validate: {
        isDate: true,
        notEmpty: true,
      },
    },
    link: {
      //...
    },
    title: {
      //...
    },
    description: {
      //...
    },
    summary: {
      //...
    },
    author: {
      //...
    },
    hash: {
      //...
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    indexes: [
      {
        fields: [{ attribute: 'pubdate', order: 'DESC' }],
        unique: false,
      },
    ],
  });

  FeedItem.associate = (models) => {
    // associations can be defined here
    //...
  };
  return FeedItem;
};
```

Migration file create-feed-item.js

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('feed_items', {
    feed_item_id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    pubdate: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    link: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    title: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    summary: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    author: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    hash: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      unique: true,
    },
  }),
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.dropTable('feed_items'),
};
```

Migration file add-index.js

```
module.exports = {
  /*
    Add altering commands here.
    Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.
    Example:
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
  */
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.addIndex('feed_items', ['pubdate'], {
    fields: [{
      attribute: 'pubdate', order: 'DESC',
    }],
    unique: false,
    name: 'feed_items_pubdate_index',
  }),
  /*
    Add reverting commands here.
    Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.
    Example:
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  */
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.removeIndex('feed_items', 'feed_items_pubdate_index'),
};
```

The migrations are run in perfect order where table is created first and index is added later.
Logging is enabled and when I check the logs

Expected:
It should create a DESC index on pubdate which goes like

```
CREATE INDEX "feed_items_pubdate_index" ON "feed_items" ("pubdate" DESC)
```

Actual Output

```
Executing (default): CREATE INDEX "feed_items_pubdate_index" ON "feed_items" ("pubdate")
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is still relevant because it is undocumented.

The proper way to define index in descending order is extended definition in `fields` argument.

So the migration file `add-index.js` should look like:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.addIndex(
    'feed_items', 
    [{
      attribute: 'pubdate', order: 'DESC',
    }], 
    {
      unique: false,
      name: 'feed_items_pubdate_index',
    }
  ),
  ...
};
```

Resolved [issue reference](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1254#issuecomment-33803527).

Answer (score 0):

use uniqueKeys:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      order: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    },
    {
      uniqueKeys: {
        actions_unique: {
          fields: ["name", "order"],
        },
      },
    }
    );
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

Comment: The bad thing about uniqueKeys is that it is only useful if you're adding a 'unique' index. But what if you want to add a non-unique index?